# How to improve a plot with a long numpy.arange array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Im using numpy.arange to generate an array with 5,5*10**6 and it has been a problem. It is taking too much time to plot the graph and when I tested with smaller numbers the code has been faster. How can I improve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.read_csv('D:\Downloads\malaria_incluso.csv', sep=';')

x = data['c_mean_acum_2000_2017']
y = data['n']
X = sm.add_constant(x)
res = sm.OLS(y, X, missing = 'drop').fit()

ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='c_mean_acum_2000_2017', y='n', hue='region', ci = None, s=50)
ax.set(xlabel='Average Incidence between 2000 and 2017', ylabel='Number of articles')
ax.set(xlim=(-10**5, 6*10**6))
sns.lineplot(np.arange(5,5*10**6),res.params[0] + np.arange(5,5*10**6)*res.params[1], linewidth = 3, color = 'gray', label = "Fitted line")

plt.show()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use 5 million points just to draw a straight line. Just create an array with two points:  `x = np.array(5,5*10**6)` or `x = np.linspace(5,5*10**6,2)` and then `sns.lineplot(x,res.params[0] + x*res.params[1], ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try to use

```
plt.plot(np.arange(5,5*10**6), res.params[0] + np.arange(5,5*10**6)*res.params[1], linewidth = 3, color = 'gray', label = "Fitted line")
```

instead of `seaborn.lineplot(...)`.

**Update:**

You can turn-off confidence intervals by `seaborn.lineplot(..., ci=None)` to make it much faster.

Comment: This will still be very slow. `np.arange(5,5*10**6)` really isn't a good idea here.

Comment: @JohanC On my device, `seaborn.lineplot()` uses more than 10 seconds and `plt.pyplot()` uses about 2 seconds.

Comment: @JohanC, you are right in your comment under the question. But I am considering a more general case.

Comment: In a more general case, it still isn't usefull to use many more x-positions than there a pixels on the screen (or dots on a printed page). You'd use `np.linspace(5,5*10**6,1000)`